# App getting crashed after updating in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have submitted a new version of my app in appstore.

When i updated my current version of the  app it is getting crashed.

But,when i deleted the app and downloaded it again it works fine.

Can anyone tell me what actually happens when we update an existing app without deleting it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Core Data and updated the model in the update? If yes it crashes because of a model mismatch.

Comment: im saving the datas parsed from the xml using NSUserdefaults.

Comment: Please add the relevant piece of code that is causing the crash to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say it without any other informations. What you can do to check what is not working is creating an adhoc of the previous version of your application and put it on your device. Then using XCode compile and install the new version of your app (this should update the adhoc installed) and launch the application. The XCode debugger should display error messages that will help to detect what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to your application crash log that you can get it via the Xcode organizer. The app crash log might provide some hint where the crash occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reinstall application, sometimes appstore corrupt binaries and this is Apple's fail.